# Property with type 'some View' cannot override a property with type 'some View'

Tags: swiftui

I would like to override a computed property with the type 'some View' in my subclass to return a different View but I'm getting this odd error:

```
open class A {
   open var oneView: some View { ...
}

public class B : A {
   public override var oneView: some View { ...
}
```

> Property with type 'some View' cannot override a property with type
>   'some View'

How is it done properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap each one in `AnyView`. It works like so:

```
open class A {

    open var oneView: AnyView {
        AnyView(Text("A"))
    }
}

public class B: A {

    public override var oneView: AnyView {
        AnyView(Text("B"))
    }
}
```

If you want to have a `VStack` inside the view body for example, you just need to make sure to wrap it in `AnyView`.

Comment: Well ... this would work but you need access to class A.

Comment: @georgij I don't understand what you mean. From your original question, I'm assuming class `B` can access `A` already?

Comment: I mean by access the possibility to change class A to have AnyView. (sorry was a bit misleading)

Comment: @georgij I don’t believe this is possible, unless `B` contains the exact same types of views. `some View` has an underlying concrete type, so unless this is matched perfectly, I don’t believe what you are trying is possible.

Comment: @georgij But if the underlying type of `A` is `Text` for example, `B` must also be `Text`. `some` is just a keyword to simplify, rather than explicitly defining the type.

Comment: yeah, that's probably the problem.